# Using xkb command to change keyboard mapping results in read-only files

Tags: readonly

I am new to Linux and maybe the answer to my question is too simple but I did my research and found nothing out there.

The key "a" in my laptop is broken. So I need to remap it in another position. I opened the location /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ and tried to edit the file "us" which contains the mapping for the English keyboard but when I tried editing it in "vi" editor I got a "read only" message. I need to edit and save the changed file. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try as super user with `sudo` ?

Comment: I did. Actually, I tried it even before you told me but I did it wrong (I am such a noob). Now that I did that, and followed every instruction here: https://radu.cotescu.com/remapping-keys-in-ubuntu-14.04/  but the changes did not apply. (I did save the file, and deleted the cache and restarted the machine)